# Find a gap between time stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have many many rows in the table. The table has a Date column (which includes date and time)

I want to be able to loop through the table and find any gap between the two rows where the difference between the row is 5 min.

For example:

```
ID Date
1 2014-07-29 13:00:00
2 2014-07-29 13:01:00
3 2014-07-29 13:07:00
```

So as you can see the time difference between the first row and second row is 1 min so I ignore, then I should be checking the time between the second row and third row. Since the time difference is 6 min I want to spit out an exception with the dates that were compared.

The table could contain many rows, so I would go and check the next record to the previous one and so one...

How could I achieve this in SQL Server. I can do a datediff, but I will have a lot of rows and I don't want to perform this manually.

Any suggestions?

NOTE* I don't need to worry about the cross over of hours from one day to another, since this task is only going to be used for a single day. I will specify on SQL statement where date = getdate()

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I don't know how you would do this with SQL Server, but this is very easily done if one queried the database using an application server and then just doing a for loop over the data.

Comment: try to use this on your procedure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17028478/no-timediff-function-in-t-sql

Comment: Are you guaranteed that ID is incremented by one for each row and the timestamp of the later row is larger?

Comment: No,IDs are random. I just gave that as an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One way to do it

```
WITH ordered AS
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) rn
    FROM table1 
)
SELECT o1.id id1, o1.date date1, o2.id id2, o2.date date2, DATEDIFF(s, o1.date, o2.date) diff
  FROM ordered o1 JOIN ordered o2
    ON o1.rn + 1 = o2.rn 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(s, o1.date, o2.date) > 60
```

Output:

```
| ID1 |                       DATE1 | ID2 |                       DATE2 | DIFF |
|-----|-----------------------------|-----|-----------------------------|------|
|   2 | July, 29 2014 13:01:00+0000 |   3 | July, 29 2014 13:07:00+0000 |  360 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a40a1/8)** demo

Comment: +1 because this will work from SQL Server 2005 onwards. What would be the performance difference between a solution with self-join and one with analytical functions assuming indexes are in place?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are on SQL Server 2012, you can make use of the `LEAD` and `LAG` functions, like so:

```
;with cte as
(select id, 
 [date], 
 datediff(minute,[date],lead([date],1,0) over (order by [date])) difference,
 row_number() over (order by [date]) rn
from tbl)

select * from cte
where rn <> 1 --Skip first row ordered by the date
and difference > 5
```

This will return all rows which have a difference of more than 5 minutes with the next row. The assumption is that the rows are sorted in ascending order of date.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/TFQNH17288)

Comment: It almost work. Please look at this [link]http://rextester.com/FRXYI94338 The time difference between the first row and second row it's 7 min, so it should return the first date and second date. The difference between second and third row is 1 min ignore, the difference between third row and fourth row it's 12 min. So it should return third row date and fourth row date.

Comment: You can remove the `where rn<>1` condition to get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you can leverage the ID column being ascending and incrementing by one:

```
select a.id, b.id, a.date, b.date
  from mytable a
  join mytable b
    on b.id = a.id - 1
 where datediff(minute, a.date, b.date) < 5
```

If you cannot leverage that:

```
with x as (
select row_number() over(order by date) as rownum, date
  from mytable
)
select a.rownum, b.rownum, a.date, b.date
  from x a
  join x b
    on b.rownum = a.rownum - 1
 where datediff(minute, a.date, b.date) < 5
```